# Should I use my own domain in my proton mail?

Tags: email, domain

Using my own domain on Proton Mail is cool, but what if someone hack my namecheap account? What if some government orders that my domain is redirected?

Should I use @protonmail instead of @mydomain? What are the implications?

Comment: Questions: why do you think some government would come after you personally ? What makes you think you are more likely to be targeted than say, Proton Mail themselves ? And if you have your own domain name why not host your mail yourself rather than trust a third party (Proton Mail) that may be good and ethical, but still subject to surveillance attempts ?

Answer (score 1):

Receiving mail is done by the recipients mail server looking up the DNS MX record. If someone can change the MX record of your domain it can thus cause mails to you to be directed to a different mail server (likely in the attackers control). Since Proton Mail is thus not involved in these mails it also cannot protect these.

The security of the already received mails is not changed though and also not the security of the sent mails. If DNS settings like SPF are changed it might be though that recipients will consider mails send with your domain as sender as spam, since they came from an unexpected IP address.

Comment: In addition to this and perhaps somewhat off topic, the domain registrar you are talking about offers two factor authentication which I highly recommend using. This lowers the likelihood of your account being compromised.